# unzip unix command

Tags: shell, unix, unzip

I have a zipped log file. However when I try to

```
unzip nameofFile.log.zip
```

I get the following error:

```
Archive:  nameofFile.log.zip
error:  cannot create nameofFile.log
```

what would be stopping it from creating the log?

Comment: Make sure you have write permissions to current directory. What is the output of 'ls -l .` for you? (I am interested only in the line showing `.`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check file creation permissions for active user. Seems that the current user has no permissions to create a new file.

Answer (score 0):

No permission to write in current directory?
Directory of name `nameofFile.log` already exists?

Comment: I wish the file already existed, however, it does not. I'm logged in as the user that created the account and as Super User, even chmod 777 the file. It seems more like the cmd is failing.